# Overlay of several Raster layers with a complex ifelse function

Tags: r, if-statement, overlay, raster

I want to perform an overlay (package Raster) of 3 raster files in R with a complex ifelse function:

```
Raster <- RasterSPI

fun1 <- function(x,y,z) {

    if (is.na(x[]) || is.na(y[]) || is.na(z[])){
      Raster[] = NA
    } else if (x[] > 0) {
      Raster[] = 1 
    } else if (y[] > 0) {
      Raster = 2
    } else if ((x[] > 0 || y[] > 0) && z[] > 0){
      Raster[] = 3 
    } else {
      Raster = 0 
    }
}

Raster <- stack(RasterSPI, RasterICE, RasterNDVI)
Raster <- overlay(RasterSPI, RasterICE, RasterNDVI, 
                    fun = function(x,y,z){
                            fun1(RasterSPI[], RasterICE[], RasterNDVI[])
                  })
```

It takes so long that I have to shut down R. Is it possible to perform a similar overlay in R that works? (overlay function of another package, reformulating the `ifelse()` function,...?)

Comment: what is `Raster` in the function? is it `RasterSPI` or the stack of three raster layers? Other than that, the `fun` argument in the `overlay` function should be equal to `fun1`.

Comment: `Raster` is the resulting raster-file from the overlay